# How to find gap date and minimum date in the same query?

Tags: t-sql, date

I have a table *customer_history* which log *customer_id* and *modification_date*.
When *customer_id* is not modified there is no entry in the table
I can find when *customer_id* haven't been modified (*=last_date_with_no_modification*). I look for when the date is missing (= Gaps and Islands problem).

But in the same query if no date is missing the value *last_date_with_no_modification* should
be `DATEADD(DAY,-1,min(modification_date))` for the *customer_id*.

I don't know how to add this last condition in my SQL query?

I use following tables:

**"Customer_history" table**:

```
customer_id modification_date
1    2017-12-20
1    2017-12-19
1    2017-12-17
2    2017-12-20
2    2017-12-18
2    2017-12-17
2    2017-12-15
3    2017-12-20
3    2017-12-19
```

**"#tmp_calendar" table:**

```
date
2017-12-15
2017-12-16
2017-12-17
2017-12-18
2017-12-19
2017-12-20
```

**Query used to qet gap date:**

```
WITH CTE_GAP AS 
(SELECT ch.customer_id,
    LAG(ch.modification_date) OVER(PARTITION BY ch.customer_id ORDER BY ch.modification_date) as GapStart,
    ch.modification_date as GapEnd,
    (DATEDIFF(DAY,LAG(ch.modification_date) OVER(PARTITION BY ch.customer_id ORDER BY ch.modification_date), ch.modification_date)-1) GapDays
FROM customer_history ch  ) 
SELECT  cg.customer_id,
    DATEADD(DAY,1,MAX(cg.GapStart)) as last_date_with_no_modification   
FROM CTE_GAP cg
CROSS JOIN #tmp_calendar c
WHERE cg.GapDays >0
AND c.date BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,1,cg.GapStart) AND DATEADD(DAY,-1,cg.GapEnd)
GROUP BY cg.customer_id
```

**Result:**

```
customer_id last_date_with_no_modification
1    2017-12-18
2    2017-12-19
3    2017-12-19 (Row missing)
```

How to get *customer_id* 3?

Answer (score 0):

Something this should work:

```
WITH CTE_GAP
AS 
(
    SELECT
        ch.customer_id,
        LAG(ch.modification_date) OVER(PARTITION BY ch.customer_id ORDER BY ch.modification_date) as GapStart,
        ch.modification_date as GapEnd,
        (DATEDIFF(DAY,LAG(ch.modification_date) OVER(PARTITION BY ch.customer_id ORDER BY ch.modification_date), ch.modification_date)-1) GapDays
    FROM @customer_history ch
)

SELECT DISTINCT
    C.customer_id
    , ISNULL(LD.last_date_with_no_modification, LD_NO_GAP.last_date_with_no_modification) last_date_with_no_modification
FROM
    customer_history C
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                cg.customer_id,
                DATEADD(DAY, 1, MAX(cg.GapStart)) last_date_with_no_modification
            FROM
                CTE_GAP cg
                CROSS JOIN #tmp_calendar c
            WHERE
                cg.GapDays >0
                AND c.date BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, 1, cg.GapStart) AND DATEADD(DAY, -1, cg.GapEnd)
            GROUP BY cg.customer_id
        ) LD
    ON C.customer_id = LD.customer_id
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                customer_id
                , DATEADD(DAY, -1, MIN(modification_date)) last_date_with_no_modification
            FROM customer_history
            GROUP BY customer_id
        ) LD_NO_GAP
    ON C.customer_id = LD_NO_GAP.customer_id
```

Comment: You're welcome! Please mark the answer as correct if it's working.